# Overloading an input operator

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, bigint

Currently have a assignment in which I've to create my own BigInt class. The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how I would be able to overload the input operator the same way I've overloaded =.

My header file is as follows:

```
#ifndef BIGINT_BIGINT_H
#define BIGINT_BIGINT_H

#include <iostream>

#define BIGINT_SIZE 256

class Bigint {
    public:
        friend std::ostream& operator>> (std::ostream& out, const Bigint& n);

        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Bigint& n);

        // the binary + operator
        Bigint operator+ (const Bigint& n);

        // the binary - operator
        Bigint operator- (const Bigint& n);

        // the binary * operator
        Bigint operator* (const Bigint& n);

        // the binary / operator
        Bigint operator/ (const Bigint& n);

        // the binary = operator:   bigint = bigint
        Bigint& operator= (const Bigint& n);

        // the binary = operator with int:   bigint = int
        Bigint& operator= (int n);

        // the constructor and destructor
        Bigint(int size = BIGINT_SIZE) {digits = size; number = new char[digits]; }

        ~Bigint() { delete[] number; }


    private:
        int  digits;
        char *number;
};


#endif //BIGINT_BIGINT_H
```

And my cpp file is:

```
#include "Bigint.h"
#include <iostream>


std::istream& operator>> () {

}


std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Bigint& n) {
    int cntr = 0;

    while ((n.number[cntr] == 0) && (cntr < n.digits-1))
        cntr++;

        while (cntr < n.digits)
            out << (int)n.number[cntr++];

            return out;
}


Bigint& Bigint::operator= (int n) {
    int cntr;

    cntr = digits - 1;
    while (cntr >= 0) {
        number[cntr--] = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    return *this;
}

Bigint Bigint::operator+ (const Bigint& n) {
    Bigint sum( (digits > n.digits) ? digits : n.digits );
    int nptr, myptr, sumptr;
    char next_n1, next_n2;
    char carry = 0;

    for (sumptr = sum.digits - 1, myptr = digits - 1, nptr = n.digits - 1; sumptr >= 0; sumptr--, myptr--, nptr--) {
        next_n1 = (nptr < 0) ? 0 : n.number[nptr];
        next_n2 = (myptr < 0) ? 0 : number[myptr];
        sum.number[sumptr] = next_n1 + next_n2 + carry;
        if (sum.number[sumptr] > 9) {
            carry = 1;
            sum.number[sumptr] -= 10;
        }
        else{
            carry = 0;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

I've only actually implemented code to handle the + and = so far.

Comment: Suggestion: Make `Bigint operator+(const Bigint& n);` and the likes into free functions. Add member functions like `Bigint& operator+=(const Bigint& n);` instead. The free functions can then use the member functions. If you want to keep `Bigint operator+(const Bigint& n);` etc as member functions, they should be `Bigint operator+(const Bigint& n) const;`

Comment: Please add a bit more implementation details of your class. How are you going to store the bytes in the `char` array. Plain ASCII characters, binary or some other encoding? Little endian, big endian? How do you keep track of the available space in `Bigint` objetct?

Answer (score 2):

First

```
friend std::ostream& operator>> (std::ostream& out, const Bigint& n);
```

should be

```
friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Bigint& n);
```

for the input operator overload.
Then in the .cpp file the definition would something like this:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Bigint& n)
{
    //take the inputs you want
    in >> n.digits;
    if (in)        // check that the inputs succeeded
     {
     //do something if succeded
     }
    else
    {
      //n = Bigint();//usually we set n to a default constructed object 
    }
     return in;

}
```

The `if` checks whether the reads were successful. If for some reason an IO error occurs, the operator resets its given object to the empty Bigint. That way the object is guaranteed to be in a *consistent state*.

Note also that `const` is not needed for the second parameter `n` of input operator because we will change its state inside the body.